# Adding relators and normal closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I learned the notion of group presentation. By definition, a group described by a presentation is the quotient of some free group by the normal closure of the relators. In general, given a group presentation, is it true that a group obtained by a new presentation by adding some relators is exactly the same as the quotient group of the normal closure(in the original presentation group) of the relators?

I can easily see that the normal closure is contained in the kernel of the natural surjective homomorphism, but I cannot prove the converse. If it is not true, what conditions make it true?

Comment: The answer is yes and it seems to me that the proof is straightforward. I cannot tell from what you have written what it is that you can easily see. Why don't you ask the question using mathematical notation rather than words?

Comment: Letting $N_Q(A)$ denote the normal closure of a finite set $A$ in a group $Q$ of which it's a subset, and $F$ some free group of which $A$ and $B$ are (finite) subsets, you want to let $G =  F/N_F(A)$ and ask whether $$ F/N_F(A \cup B) = G/N_G(B'),$$ where $B'$ is the image of $B \subset F$ under the quotient $F \to F/N_F(A)$. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly. I was on my mobile phone and it made some display error with TeX.. It's okay now.

Comment: @JohnHughes That's really horrible notation! $N_Q(A)$ denotes the normalizer of $A$ in $Q$. The normal closure is $\langle A^Q \rangle$.

Comment: You're right, Derek. Anyone who answers should use Derek's suggested notation rather than mine. (I can no longer edit my comment, alas).